# github authentication / permissions: multiple users, multiple repos

Tags: git, permissions, push

I cannot get github to permit me to upload files to my repo.  I share this machine, and I re-went through the steps on github for account setup; moving ALL of both of our SSH keys to a backup and redoing it basically from scratch.

I've referenced a couple other questions on here, but neither have been working for me.  The error I am getting is:

> git push -u origin master
>
> ERROR: Permission to [repository] denied to [user].
>
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Others have cited that the public key needs to be added to git.  I've already done this [multiple times], and still no dice.

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the repository belongs to another account than the one set on your machine, I think you need to add a "collaborator" on your project.

Comment: Yes, github actually JUST got back to me to tell me to add the other user on my machine as a collaborator.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `https://github.com/yourusername/yourrepo.git` to clone and push to the repository. This will ask you for the username and password every time you push. This might be the right way on a shared machine